# Is there a need of the "the-that" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are 11 questions using [the-that](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-that), without tag wiki, including the following ones:

- [When to use "That" instead of "The"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/406269/when-to-use-that-instead-of-the)
- [When can one omit "that" from a sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/170112/when-can-one-omit-that-from-a-sentence)
- [Comma after "that" midsentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/151586/comma-after-that-midsentence)

While I could see a use for the tag in the first question, I think that using [the-that](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-that) to mean *the question is about "the" or "that"* is quite wrong.
For questions comparing *the* and *that* the tag could make sense, but I don't think there are enough questions to justify a specific tag when there are already less specific tags, but still specific enough to be used.

Do we really want to keep it?

Comment: What are the less-specific specific-enough tags which could be used?

Comment: It depends from the question: If it is about the words usage, there is [tag:word-usage]; if it's about choosing a word, there is [tag:word-choice]; if it's about using _that_ as pronoun, there are [tag:pronouns] and related tags.

Comment: I agree. Just nuke it.

Comment: @DanBron *[burninate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7gz1DIIxmEE)...

Comment: Seems like one of the tags where burnination is not enough, do we have a tag guillotine?